# How do command line options work in xfreerdp 2.2.0?

Tags: linux, command-line, remote-desktop

On Ubuntu 20.04, I have:

```
$ xfreerdp --version
This is FreeRDP version 2.2.0 (n/a)
```

The man page I see for `man xfreerdp` seems to be the same as in https://www.mankier.com/1/xfreerdp

Now, in older man pages like https://linux.die.net/man/1/xfreerdp, there is a mention of this:

> ```
>     --no-fastpath 
>
> Disables fast-path. Use slow-path packets instead, which have larger
> headers. It might be good for debugging certain issues when you
> suspect it might be linked to the parsing of one of the two header
> types.
> ```

Ok, but in my man page and https://www.mankier.com/1/xfreerdp - there is no such mention; instead, there is:

> ```
>  /f
>
>     Fullscreen mode (<Ctrl>+<Alt>+<Enter> toggles fullscreen)
>
> -fast-path
>
>     fast-path input/output (default:on)
>
> +fipsmode
>
>     FIPS mode (default:off)
> ```

So, if `-fast-path` is (default:on), how do I turn it off??

The great thing about this man page is that it does not explain how arguments work (Ctrl-F `+` - ton of results, nothing explanatory; Ctrl-F `plus` - no results):

- it might be that I have to prepend `--no` to `-fast-path` (as in older man), that is, specify `--no-fast-path` to turn it off;
- it might be that I simply do not have to specify `-fast-path` at all at the command line, to have it turned off
- though from the above snippet, I might guess that `-` in front of an argument turns it ON, `+` in front of an argument turns it OFF (though that is kind of inverted logic; and man also says `+clipboard  Activate clipboard redirection` which is opposite of what I've deduced) - and then `/` in front of an argument means ... who knows what.

So, how do command line arguments in `xfreerdp` work? Is this documented anywhere?

More specifically, how to be explicit about turning off `-fast-path` on the command line?

---

EDIT: just to add to the confusion, I found this post: [Connecting to Windows 2012/2012R2/2016/10 with -fast-path and non-RGX/GFX color depth gives a black screen · Issue #4642 · FreeRDP/FreeRDP · GitHub](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/4642)

> ... with disabled fast-path (-fast-path)

... so, they claim `-fast-path` *disables* fast-path - which in my mind, is the opposite claim of "-fast-path fast-path input/output (default:on)" claim in the (new) man page?

How come no one ever got confused by this? `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally found the explanation - it's in `--help`:

```
$  xfreerdp --help

FreeRDP - A Free Remote Desktop Protocol Implementation
See www.freerdp.com for more information

Usage: xfreerdp [file] [options] [/v:<server>[:port]]

Syntax:
    /flag (enables flag)
    /option:<value> (specifies option with value)
    +toggle -toggle (enables or disables toggle, where '/' is a synonym of '+')
```

OK, so then `-fast-path` disables fast-path; `+fast-path` or `/fast-path` enables it ...